# Replace an older promise with a newer one in a jquery deferred chain

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have an object that uses jQuery's `Deferred` to create my own promise that I resolve after a timeout. I then chain an ajax call, and return the promise.

```
var Obj = function() {
  var _obj = new $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
      _obj.resolve("Resolve One!");
  }, 2000);

  return _obj.promise();
}

new Obj()
.done(function(message) {
  document.write(message);
  return $.get("http://www.jsonip.com/");
})
.done(function(response) {
  document.write(response);
})
```

I'd expect message to have "Resolve One!" and response to have the response from the ajax call

Result expected:

```
Resolve One!{"ip":"256.256.0.0","about":"/about"}
```

What I get instead:

```
Resolve One!Resolve One!
```

Since I'm returning `$.get()`, which is a promise, I'd expect the old promise to be overridden with the one from jQuery. What should I be doing instead, to get the the web page contents into response`?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zUKg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.done` only adds the handler. You want `.then`, which also allows you to return a new promise: http://jsfiddle.net/7zUKg/1/.

```
new Obj()
.then(function(message) {
  document.write(message);
  return $.get("http://www.jsonip.com/");
})
.done(function(response) {
  document.write(response);
})
```

Comment: I'm sure this answer is correct, but you should also put brackets round `(new Obj())`, otherwise `new` will try to apply itself to whatever is returned by the right hand end of the method chain. The "member" operator `.` has higher precedence than `new`, so the entire method chain will execute first. Due to the nature of `Obj()`, (a) lack of brackets may not be an issue in this case, and (b) `new` can be omitted.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I'm not sure if that's correct. `new A.b()` requires brackets but `new A().b()` does not. The `new` has higher precedence in that case.